# Manual loop unrolling with known maximum size

Tags: opencl, loop-unrolling

Please take a look at this code in an OpenCL kernel:

```
uint point_color = 4278190080;
float point_percent = 1.0f;
float near_pixel_size = (...);
float far_pixel_size = (...);
float delta_pixel_size = far_pixel_size - near_pixel_size;
float3 near = (...);
float3 far = (...);
float3 direction = normalize(far - near);

point_position = (...) + 10;
for (size_t p = 0; p < point_count; p++, position += 4)
{
    float3 point = (float3)(point_list[point_position], point_list[point_position + 1], point_list[point_position + 2]);
    float projection = dot(point - near, direction);
    float3 projected = near + direction * projection;
    float rejection_length = distance(point, projected);
    float percent = projection / segment_length;
    float pixel_size = near_pixel_size + percent * delta_pixel_size;
    bool is_candidate = (pixel_size > rejection_length && point_percent > percent);
    point_color = (is_candidate ? (uint)point_list[point_position + 3] | 4278190080 : point_color);
    point_percent = (is_candidate ? percent : point_percent);
}
```

This code attempts to find the point in a list that is nearest to the line segment between *far* and *near*, and assigning its color to *point_color* and its "percentual distance" into *point_percent*. (Incidentally, the code seems to be OK).

The number of elements specified by *point_count* is variable, so I cannot assume too much about it, save for one thing: *point_count* will always be equal or less than 8. That's a fixed fact in my code and data.

I would like to unroll this loop manually, and I'm afraid I will need to use lots of

```
value = (point_count < constant ? new_value : value)
```

for all lines in it. In your experience, will such a strategy increase performance in my kernel?

And yes, I know, I should be performing some benchmarking by myself; I just wanted to ask someone with lots of experience in OpenCL before actually attempting this on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Most OpenCL drivers (that I'm familiar with, at least) support the use of `#pragma unroll` to unroll loops at compile time. Simply use it like so:

```
#pragma unroll
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    /* ... */
}
```

It's effectively the same as unrolling it manually, with none of the effort. In your case, this would probably look more like:

```
if (pointCount == 1) {
    /* ... */
} else if (pointCount == 2) {
    #pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { /* ... */ }
} else if (pointCount == 3) { 
    #pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I can't say for certain whether there will be an improvement, but there's one way to find out. If `pointCount` is constant for the local work group for example, it might improve performance, but if it's completely variable, this might actually make things worse.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/nv/cl_nv_pragma_unroll.txt).